# Taking screenshot of dropdown list in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have code for taking screenshot of web apps in QTP.
At one instance i want to take screenshot of the dropdown list with the list showing but not able to manage that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, hope this helps...

```
SystemUtil.Run "Iexplore.exe","http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dropdm.htm"
strPath="C:\dropdown_screenshot.bmp"

Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")=2
Browser("Browser").Page("What is dropdown menu?").WebList("s").Click
Browser("Browser").Page("What is dropdown menu?").CaptureBitmap(strPath)
Browser("Browser").Page("What is dropdown menu?").WebList("s").Select "Choice 2"
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType")=1
```

Dropdown list screenshot was captured successfully.

[image]